electron auto update not working after removing code signing from Electron app deployment
electron-builder : 21.2.0
Electron Version: 7.3.3
Electron Updater: 4.3.5
Target: Windows
I was distributing my Electron app by code signing, but since the certificate expired, I removed the code signing-related sources and distributed the app. Now, I'm encountering an error with the auto-updater, and automatic updates are not working. What should I do? The error message is as follows:
[2024-10-15 16:00:40.289] [info] Error: New version 1.1.31 is not signed by the application owner: publisherNames: ARR CO,.Ltd, raw info: {
  "SignerCertificate": null,
  "TimeStamperCertificate": null,
  "Status": 2,
  "StatusMessage": "C:\\Users\\owner\\AppData\\Local\\11-updater\\pending\\temp-11-setup-1.1.31.exe 파일이 디지털 서명되지 않았습니다. 현재 시스템에서 이 스크립트를 실행할 수 없습니다. 스크립트 실행 및 실행 정책 설정에 대한 자세한 내용은 about_Execution_Policies(https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170)를 참조하십시오."
}
    at t.newError (C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\11\resources\app.asar\background.js:1:5792)
    at Object.task (C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\11\resources\app.asar\background.js:1:162458)
    at async m.executeDownload (C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\11\resources\app.asar\background.js:1:72345)

This is my electron-builder configuration for Windows:
win: {
    icon: '../public/icon/main.ico',
    target: [
                {
            target: 'nsis',
            arch: ['ia32'],
             },
        ],
      },

